# I'm trying to rotate a chevronDown button in react.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to rotate a chevronDown button in react.js but the button is static.

here is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

import { chevronDown } from '../assets';
import styles from '../styles';
import { useOnClickOutside } from '../utils';

const AmountIn = () => {
  const [showList, setShowList] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={styles.amountContainer}>
      <input
        placeholder="0.0"
        type="number"
        value=""
        disabled={false}
        onChange={() => {}}
        className={styles.amountInput}
      />
      
      <div className="relative" onClick={() => setShowList((prevState) => !prevState)}>
        <button className={styles.currencyButton}>
          {"ETH"}
          <img
            src={chevronDown}
            alt="chevron down"
            className={'w-4 h-4 object-contain ml-2 ${showList ? 'rotate-180' : 'rotate-0'}'}
          />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AmountIn
```

I'm expecting the button to rotate when the cursor is pointed at the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the CSS `:hover` selector using [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). In your CSS module, you would use something like this to flip a chevron around

```css
.currencyButton {
  // core styling
  &:hover {
    img {
      transform: rotate(0.5turn);
    }
  }
}
```

To expand on that, you can animate the change using a CSS [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).